# Completion handler called twice (with threading)

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler, dispatch-queue, ios-multithreading

I'm currently testing this code in the Xcode 10 playground (Swift 5):

```
func one() {
    let test = "bla"
    two(test, completion: { (returned) in
        print(returned)
        })
}

func two(_ test: String, completion: @escaping (_ returned: String?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
        if !test.isEmpty {
            //Some slow stuff
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                return completion("hi!")

            }
        }

        //Also some slow stuff
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            return completion(nil) //can't have this in "else"!
        }
    }
}

one()
```

The problem is that both "hi" and "nil" are printed.

If I get rid of the threading, it works fine but with it it seems like it gets to the second `DispatchQueue.main.async` before the first has the chance to return.

There's a lot more stuff going on in the "Some slow stuff" `if` in my actual code but I can't rely on that taking long enough to return before the second return is called too.

How do I accomplish this: Have the function run in a background thread but return only once on the main thread (like code without threading normally would)?

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want to execute both sets of slow stuff? Do you want just a single completion call?

Comment: I want to call the `if` and the "slow stuff" within, then call the completion handler to get the result back to `one()`. If the `if` doesn't trigger, I only want to call the "Also some slow stuff" and return `nil`.

Comment: Check out my answer below.  I think it does what you want.  I'm curious why the second slow stuff couldn't be in an `else`.

Comment: In this test (in the playground) it could be in an `else` but in my real app it's basically a long list of `if`s with only a single good outcome. Of course I could just return in every `else` but I also have to do some other stuff before I do (e.g. close sockets) and then the same code would be in there appr. 10 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your goal is to only call the `completion` handler once, and when you do you are done.  In that case, call `return` in the `.background` thread after queueing the completion call on the main thread:

```
func two(_ test: String, completion: @escaping (_ returned: String?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
        if !test.isEmpty {
            //Some slow stuff

            // notify main thread we're done
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion("hi!")
            }

            // we are done and don't want to do more work on the
            // background thread
            return
        }

        //Also some slow stuff
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, it's really this easy and the order everything is being called in is right too. Thanks! Just wondering: Xcode doesn't complatin about `return completion("hi")` but removing it doesn't seem to make much of a difference, so what does the `return` do exactly in combination with the completion handler? Is it more of a thing like `if somebool == true` being the same as `if somebool`?

Comment: `return completion("hi!")` will call the completion handler and return the result which is `()`. Since the closure is returning anyway, the `return` is useless.

Comment: I just tested it with my actual code outside the playground and it's working perfectly there too, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why it's called twice it pretty obvious. (btw you dont return completion blocks) What you have written is this:

```
func two(_ test: String, completion: @escaping (_ returned: String?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
        if !test.isEmpty {
            //Some slow stuff
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion("hi!")

            }
        }
        completion(nil) //can't have this in "else"!
    }
}
```

And since the mainthread always keeps going while you do other things on the background threat you will get 2 completions. What you want to do i guess is to remove the second one?

Alternative is that you create a `DispatchGroup` and enter each call inside it and then write a `Dispatch wait till done` to wait for all requests to finish

Comment: `What you want to do i guess is to remove the second one?` - No, I need the second `DispatchQueue.main.async` too, otherwise `completion(nil)` will return in the background thread. I'll have to look at `DispatchGroup`s but if there's a way to do it just with the `DispatchQueue`, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defer` statement to return completion block once after all the `If` statements. Here just the example with your code, but I hope it's clear.

```
func two(_ test: String, completion: @escaping (_ returned: String?) -> Void) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {

            var resultString: String? 

            // Called only once after all code inside this async block.
            defer {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(resultString)
                }
            }

            if !test.isEmpty {

               //Some slow stuff
               resultString = "hi"

               return 
            }

            // Another stuff 
            resultString = nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I can't do "Also some slow stuff" in an `else`. So while `defer` is a good thing to use in other cases, it won't work here because if I remove the `else` around "Also some slow stuff", it'll just overwrite the result.

Comment: I understand it but overwriting of the result depend on your if statements, so you could write the statements that there wouldn't any overwrite of the result.

Comment: You can only be sure that it won't overwrite if you use an `else`, which I can't because of how my actual code is set up/works. Removing the `else` and just having `resultString = nil` there "naked" would always return `nil`.

Comment: Yeah but anyway you can mix it with "return", code will be more clear with just one return of completion block. 
Updated answer.